# Can animals graze even when there is snow on the grass?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've just started a Dwarf Fortress (0.34.11) game and I just happen to start in a location with Climate: Freezing. The ground is covered in snow, but there's grass outside and I want to make a pasture for my animals. Will they be able to graze even if the ground is covered in snow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Animals will clear the snow to get at the grass, then eat the grass and continue along their merry way.

You can pasture your animals outside without fear.

Comment: Well, without *additional* fear. There's still starvation due to too small a grazing area, death by violent animal fight, random goblin raids, "unfortunate accidents"...

Comment: @Shadur But of course! Don't discount the possibility of death by magma, either!

Comment: Isn't it also possible that they could freeze to death?

Comment: @Zibbobz I am pretty sure that only applies to naked dwarves / older versions of DF. I've never seen anything freeze to death, personally.